# I want to validate data like 111-244-123 in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to validate data like this

`three_number-three_number-three_number. It will look like 111-123-121.'

I am using Laravel. Anyone help me please to validate this kind of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [regex validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex). In your controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'field_name' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/',
    ]);

    // Use the validated value ...
    $value = $request->input('field_name');
}
```

If `field_name` does not pass the validation rule(s), Laravel will store the validation errors in the session and automatically redirect the user back.

Since v5.2 Laravel supports array field validation. So given `field_name` is an array, you can validate each of it's items with

```
'field_name.*' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/'
```

Remember to add square brackets to the name of the input i.e

```
<input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="111-123-121" />
```

Showing the errors is as easy as

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Additionally you can extract the above snippet in a shared partial and include it where necessary (preferably in the layout).

Comment: Thanks its works for me. But it is not working when I am validating for array data. this is what I used but not working.                                                    `'id'         => 'required|array|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/',
                  'id.*'       => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/',`

Comment: @fokrul Updated my answer.

Comment: You should accept an answer. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers is you need assistance

Answer (score 2):

Try with `regex` pattern like `/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/`

For Laravel: `'your_field_name' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/'`

Comment: Thanks its works for me. But it is not working when I am validating for array data. this is what I used but not working.                                                    `'id'         => 'required|array|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/',
                  'id.*'       => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/',`